# Facebook Messenger Bot - Pass control from the bot to human and enable keyboard input

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

This was probably answered but I can't find any.

I have a bot with disabled composer input. So it is controlled by buttons only. All messages appear in 'Done' folder as expected. But when I want to pass control to the human (switch to the Secondary Receiver) composer input will still be disabled.
Is there any solution to enable input when transferring chat to human and disable again when Bot controls again?